# How to use AWS Sagemaker XGBoost framework?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm building XGBoost model on sagemaker for IRIS dataset. I have two files model.py and train.py as follows:

`Model.py`:

```
import boto3, sagemaker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.xgboost.estimator import XGBoost

role = get_execution_role()
bucket_name = 'my-bucket-name'
train_prefix = 'iris_data/train'
test_prefix = 'iris_data/test'

session = boto3.Session()
sg_session = sagemaker.Session(session)

# Read training data from S3
train_channel = 's3://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket_name, train_prefix)

data_channels = {'train': train_channel}

hyperparameters = {
    'max_leaf_nodes': 30
}

model = XGBoost(entry_point="train.py",
                train_instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
                train_instance_count=1,
                role=role,
                framework_version = '0.90-2',
                sagemaker_session=sg_session,
                hyperparameters=hyperparameters)

model.fit(inputs=data_channels,  logs=True)

transformer = model.transformer(instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
test_channel = 's3://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket_name, test_prefix)

transformer.transform(test_channel, content_type='text/csv')
print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer.wait()

batch_output = transformer.output_path
print(batch_output)
```

`train.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import os
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Hyperparameters are described here. In this simple example we are just including one hyperparameter.
    parser.add_argument('--max_leaf_nodes', type=int, default=-1)

    # Sagemaker specific arguments. Defaults are set in the environment variables.
    parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Take the set of files and read them all into a single pandas dataframe
    input_files = [ os.path.join(args.train, file) for file in os.listdir(args.train) ]
    if len(input_files) == 0:
        raise ValueError(('There are no files in {}.\n' +
                          'This usually indicates that the channel ({}) was incorrectly specified,\n' +
                          'the data specification in S3 was incorrectly specified or the role specified\n' +
                          'does not have permission to access the data.').format(args.train, "train"))
    raw_data = [ pd.read_csv(file, header=None, engine="python") for file in input_files ]
    train_data = pd.concat(raw_data)

    # labels are in the first column
    train_y = train_data.iloc[:,0]
    train_X = train_data.iloc[:,1:]

    # Here we support a single hyperparameter, 'max_leaf_nodes'. Note that you can add as many
    # as your training my require in the ArgumentParser above.
    max_leaf_nodes = args.max_leaf_nodes

    # Now use scikit-learn's decision tree classifier to train the model.
    clf = XGBClassifier(max_depth=10, n_estimators=100, random_state=78432)
    clf = clf.fit(train_X, train_y)

    # Print the coefficients of the trained classifier, and save the coefficients
    pickle.dump(clf, open(os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.bin"), "wb"))    


def model_fn(model_dir):
    """Deserialized and return fitted model

    Note that this should have the same name as the serialized model in the main method
    """
    model = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.bin"), "rb"))
    return model
```

I cannot use XGBoost built-in container because I want to use XGBoost framework at the end for my work, where train.py does much more than just reading data from S3. So as of now, for testing I am checking this with IRIS data.

But when I execute model.py, model training is completed successfully but it is failing in btach transform with the following error:

```
Waiting for transform job: sagemaker-xgboost-2020-03-31-17-21-48-649
......................Processing /opt/ml/code
Building wheels for collected packages: train
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for train: filename=train-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6872 sha256=dd15ce5260f45f557b284e58a126d91440fb72155eca544c64e4faa9ce48ff38
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-zlsbuj5_/wheels/95/c1/85/65aaf48b35aba88c6e896d2fd04a4b69f1cee0d81ea32993ca
Successfully built train
Installing collected packages: train
Successfully installed train-1.0.0
[2020-03-31 17:25:18 +0000] [38] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0
[2020-03-31 17:25:18 +0000] [38] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (38)
[2020-03-31 17:25:18 +0000] [38] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2020-03-31 17:25:18 +0000] [41] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 41
[2020-03-31 17:25:18 +0000] [45] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45
[2020-03-31 17:25:19 +0000] [46] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 46
[2020-03-31 17:25:19 +0000] [47] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47
[2020-03-31:17:25:53:INFO] No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
[2020-03-31:17:25:53:INFO] Installing module with the following command:
/miniconda3/bin/python -m pip install . 
Processing /opt/ml/code
Building wheels for collected packages: train
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for train: filename=train-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6871 sha256=e8f227b103bf75716d7967683595b4e6d5caacd312a79b5231b8f653225be8d0
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-hlc0kry6/wheels/95/c1/85/65aaf48b35aba88c6e896d2fd04a4b69f1cee0d81ea32993ca
Successfully built train
Installing collected packages: train
  Attempting uninstall: train
    Found existing installation: train 1.0.0
    Uninstalling train-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled train-1.0.0
Successfully installed train-1.0.0
169.254.255.130 - - [31/Mar/2020:17:25:55 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
[2020-03-31:17:25:55:INFO] No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
[2020-03-31:17:25:55:INFO] Installing module with the following command:
/miniconda3/bin/python -m pip install . 
Processing /opt/ml/code
Building wheels for collected packages: train
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for train (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for train: filename=train-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6870 sha256=dab9513d234f721f798249797424c388f0659588903c01880dc21811e1bf4ea5
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-j30gnab9/wheels/95/c1/85/65aaf48b35aba88c6e896d2fd04a4b69f1cee0d81ea32993ca
Successfully built train
Installing collected packages: train
  Attempting uninstall: train
    Found existing installation: train 1.0.0
    Uninstalling train-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled train-1.0.0
Successfully installed train-1.0.0
169.254.255.130 - - [31/Mar/2020:17:25:56 +0000] "GET /execution-parameters HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
[2020-03-31:17:25:56:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
[2020-03-31:17:25:56:ERROR] Exception on /invocations [POST]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/serving.py", line 55, in default_input_fn
    return xgb_encoders.decode(input_data, content_type)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/encoder.py", line 121, in decode
    return decoder(obj)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/encoder.py", line 50, in csv_to_dmatrix
    np_payload = np.array(list(map(lambda x: _clean_csv_string(x, delimiter), string_like.split('\n')))).astype(dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 200, in transform
    self._model, request.content, request.content_type, request.accept
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 227, in _default_transform_fn
    data = self._input_fn(content, content_type)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 95, in wrapper
    six.reraise(error_class, error_class(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/serving.py", line 55, in default_input_fn
    return xgb_encoders.decode(input_data, content_type)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/encoder.py", line 121, in decode
    return decoder(obj)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/encoder.py", line 50, in csv_to_dmatrix
    np_payload = np.array(list(map(lambda x: _clean_csv_string(x, delimiter), string_like.split('\n')))).astype(dtype)
sagemaker_containers._errors.ClientError: setting an array element with a sequence.
169.254.255.130 - - [31/Mar/2020:17:25:56 +0000] "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

If I change my framework from XGBoost and SKLearn to run DecisionTree model, everything is working perfect and I am able to see the prediction results. Please let me know what I'm missing here and how to rectify this.

Comment: For what error are we talking about (none is shown), and what *exactly* is your question?

Comment: Arguably, `xgboost` is a much more appropriate tag here than `pandas` (edited).

Comment: Please check the whole traceback. I'm not sure whether the error is in sagemaker, pandas or xgboost. So added all the tags.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little generic, but it looks like you may need to either change your batch data or write your own input_fn in your script to handle the data format you are using.